# Export BPMN2 model into XML from MagicDraw

Tags: bpmn, magic-draw

Can I export a BPMN2 model into XML using MagicDraw 17. BPMN2 spec specifies a XML schema to represent BMPN2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the NoMagic forums: https://community.nomagic.com/export-bmpn2-to-xml-t2177.html

```
Hello,

You can export BPMN models to XPDL standard in the current version. Later you can use different type of converters to convert it to BPMN XMI (e.g. www.businessprocessincubator.com ).
BPMN2 XML export will be added in the next major Cameo Business Modeler version.

Best Regards,
Edita Mileviciene
```